# Dictionary - using type as key and constraint it to only to certain types

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

Is it possible, if we use a Type as key for a dictionary, to constrain that type only to specific ones? For example:

```
public abstract class Base
{ }

public class InheritedObject1 : Base
{ }

public class InheritedObject2 : Base
{ }

public class Program
{
    public Dictionary<Type, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, string>();
}
```

So from the code given above for instance i want to constraint the Type only to : Base and every class which inherits from it. Is it possible to make such a constraint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create a template class that inherits from `Dictionary`, as so:

```
class CustomDictionary<T> : Dictionary<T, string>
    where T : Base
{
}
```

Then you can use it in your code as required:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        CustomDictionary<InheritedObject1> Dict = new CustomDictionary<InheritedObject1>();

        Dict.Add(new InheritedObject1(), "value1");
        Dict.Add(new InheritedObject1(), "value2");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you do

```
public Dictionary<Base, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<Base, string>();
```

then only `Base` and its children will be able to be used as the key (in this specific case `Base` is `abstract` so only children applies).

Comment: This is not the same. In the question an instance of a `Type` is used as a key, while in your answer any instance of type `Base` or derived of it can be used as a key. The question is about only allowing specific types as key in the dictionary, not instances of the type.

Comment: @Maarten Given the [response of the OP to another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795436/dictionary-using-type-as-key-and-constraint-it-to-only-to-certain-types/27795564?noredirect=1#comment43999788_27795475) I assume it is just a miscommunication about the word `Type` being used.